# Hypergeometric extension to deal with double summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I would like to be able to find an expression for summations of the form
$$
\sum_{l,m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{l}y^{m}}{a^{2}+l^{2}+m^{2}},
$$
at least in terms of special functions, although I can't even see how to do this. I'm aware of hypergeometric functions that deal with the single summation version but nothing that deals with the double summation. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you can start and have a look at, for instance, [at this paper](http://www.sapub.org/global/showpaperpdf.aspx?doi=10.5923/j.ajcam.20130303.05)

Comment: If you can refactor it in terms of Pochammer symbol(s) then compare to possible series

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_function or

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html